# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que este código para hacer responsive un sitio funcione correctamente en dispositivos móviles?

Tags: css, responsive

Tengo un sitio web que es reponsive en la pc pero no consigo que sea responsive para los dispositivos moviles,y quisiera saber el porque este es el codigo que tengo:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #separador {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  hr {
    width: 100%;
  }

  #contenedor {
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  #entrada, input, button, #intentos {
    width: 100%;
  }
  input {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  button {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
}
```